# Can use "Multiple MySQL Queries with PHP" with MySQL version 4

Tags: php, mysql, multi-query

I can run multi-queries with MYSQL v5 with extension PHP :mysqli.

But with MYSQL 4 with extension PHP: mysql ..
with new query, have the problem.

I would like to verify the information and the way to resolve.

Because, the company hosting service is using mySQL v4.

Thank you

Comment: Change hosting company, MySQL 5.5 is out, 5.6 on the way, and version 4 is not supoprted since 1.1.2009!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to verify the information

Yes, you can't

> and the way to resolve.

run your queries one by one.